# Concurrency issue with C# MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web application, where I am facing a concurrency related issue. My application is basically used to create user visits. Every item contains some visit related details and multiple locations details.

My form layout is like this: [Location Form Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q78OB.png).

A user can add a maximum of 3 locations. For that, I'm using client side validation. I am using a SQL Server and Entity Framework to store my data.

***Example:***
Suppose I've created a visit, and after submission, the visit id is **121**. The visit URL might look like this:

https://www.visits.com/visit/121

If the above URL is hitting on 3 different systems, then my location validation will not work. Through **System-1**, the user can add 3 locations, and from System-2 user can add 3 locations, and so on.

But I have to restrict my user to add locations in this way.

How can I resolve this issue using some C# code?

The solution should be like, if from **System-1**, someone is trying to add locations, at the same time, if someone else is trying to add locations from **System-2**, then the System-2 user should get a message like:

> This visit edition is processing somewhere else, so please wait after some time.

Comment: Try a Semaphore (or semaphoreslim)?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of dealing with multiple logins is to build a simple WebSocket server as a Service on your Server with a Dictionary that has <"username",count> values that increments when logged in and decrements when logging out.

When you login, check if the value is greater than you allow and returns a flag if there are too many logins which sends it back to another page.  This removes the need for an extra MVC controller.

JavaScript has a super easy way of interfacing with your WebSocket server that you could take advantage of client-side.